# Change app's name cause crash on launch

Tags: ios, crash, bundle, rename, launch

I just recently change my app's name from ABCXYZ to ABC-XYZ in

```
info.plist -> Bundle Display Name
```

This cause crash on the device when launch. This is the only message:

```
DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0, cookie file:
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7CB9B0EA-97A2-4D3E-A8AA-CEB419BEB1F2/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies
```

The simulator works fine, only real device crash. What is the problem here? Will it crash when I update on appstore?

Edit 1: Everything worked super fine before I changed app name. I'll try to change to name back to see if problems gone.

Edit 2: No, it didn't work even after I change the name back. What should I do now?

Edit 3: I only change app's display name, not project name or anything else. My project name is still ABCXYZ-iPad. I think the problem is maybe because I have imported too much external framework, sdk... and it cause conflict somewhere?

Edit 4: These are all the solutions I've tried so far. No result yet.

```
0. Rename to its old name, reinstall.
1. Clean, build, reset xcode, clean, build.
2. Delete app on device, reinstall.
3. Re-download from store, reinstall.
4. Reset device, reinstall.
```

Edit 5: I just find out that my app got through this line of code.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    NSLog(@"background fetch");
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

And then write out the message above. Not sure what it mean though.

**EDIT 6: FOUND EXACTLY WHERE IT CAUSE THE CRASH!**
Many thanks to Nicholas Langley, the problems printed here:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Stripe Payment
    [Stripe setDefaultPublishableKey:StripePublishableKey];
    // iZettle Payment
    [[iZettleSDK shared] startWithAPIKey:@"THE_API_KEY"];
```

I changed my app name, cause it to change the bundle. After debugging, it prints out the message after that line of code (startWithAPIKey), and crash when I try to do this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSString *x = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"X"];
[dic setObject:x forKey@"X"]; <<< HERE ERROR SETTING NIL. STRANGE because it doesn't print any message. Also, My app should store X already.
```

It seems that after changing the app's name, it also change the bundle, which cause data loss. Now the real question is: how to migrate old data with new data after changing the app's name/bundle. The simulator doesn't produce this error, and I can't debug into device's directory to check anything.

**EDIT 7: SUDDENLY SOLVED!**

After update the app:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSString *x = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"X"];
if (x) {
    [dic setObject:x forKey@"X"];
}
```

And reinstall, it crash a few times, then work normally again. I even change the app's name a few more times, no problem occurred again. I really worry if update the app to the store will cause crash if users download and upgrade the app.

**EDIT 8: Test with upgrading from store.**
I just re-download from store old version. Then upgrade to new version (doesn't change app's name). Then change the app's name. No problem occur. The problem just disappeared, like a dream....... I don't even know what to do. This meme absolutely right in my case! Well, thanks to everyone who has spent time for reading this long article.

[image: I have no clue]

Comment: Strange ! I have renamed my demo app like 2-3 times but didn't got any crash so far. Any specific steps or change to re-produce it? Also I searched for this kinda topic and it pointed out towards the safari cookies clearing issue. Let me know if you find any solution or way to re-produce it.

Comment: You see, all I did was change the app name. Truth be told, I did some change in the code also. But that's not the problem, since the app doesn't even started. Well, I'll update the question. Please see for edit 5.

Comment: Ahahaha, nice meme! :)

Answer (score 0):

Build your project (cmd+b). Go To Product > Clean (shift+cmd+k).    Close Xcode find the project directory I.e. Desktop/ABC-XYZ and open the project by double clicking the Xcode project file.

Comment: Sorry, not working. I even reset the real device the problem still occurred. Really worry if I have to make customer reset/reinstall the whole app. It may cause their data to loss.

Comment: "I think the problem is maybe because I have imported too much external framework, sdk... and it cause conflict somewhere" What frameworks are you using?

Comment: iZettle, authorize.net, crash reporter, libScanapi64, some built-in frameworks... I don't think that's the problem anymore :(

Comment: Are you using Cordova?

Comment: Nope. I just did some research and found about that cordova cause the similar error. But I don't use Cordova.

Comment: We more in depth explanation of how your app is using cookies and why? Something to do with cookie handling, I suspect your may need to update one of your frameworks..

Comment: I don't even know where it using cookie. But, well, probably the synchronize with server function.

Comment: is performFetchWithCompletionHandler in App Delegate? is it printing "background fetch" in your log?

Don't you have to register your bundle ID with iZettle?

Comment: Oh, right! I'll check right away! And, yes, performFetchWithCompletionHandler in AppDelegate, and it prints "background fetch" in my log (when reinstall), well, not all the times, but sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close Xcode and all editors.
2. Copy your project folder.
3. Create a new folder, e.g. Documents\Projects\Proj_1.
4. Paste your project files into here.
5. Open Xcode, clean solution and try reinstall to your device.

Maybe the problem is in your hard drive. My variant changes the location of your files and this changes the addresses of project files in your hard drive.